# Gödel's loophole

Tags: goedel, politics

Gödel's loophole is an unidentified, alleged contradiction in the US Constitution, one that purportedly allows for America to transform into a tyranny on an internal "legal" basis. Since Gödel never really clarified what he was talking about, identifying this flaw has become an exercise in either Gödel exegesis or Constitutional interpretation. I haven't studied this topic in great detail, but what I've gleaned so far is that the culprit principle is often supposed to be the amendment process, in that it seems as if it would be possible to amend the Constitution in favor of tyranny (and by now, we even live in an America where it would not be surprising if many, if not most, states went on to ratify such an amendment).

However, I don't know that the amendment process is a *contradiction*. In fact, the US Constitution is a somewhat amorphous document, and I would be at pains to declare anything in it to be clearly incoherent in the required way: due to the amorphousness issue, I could see an alleged contradiction being attributed to misreading of the document rather than to its "genuine content."

That being said, there is a *thematic* tension, in American society, perhaps reflected in the Constitution proper somewhere: the tension between majority rule as necessary for freedom on one level, and minority protections as necessary for freedom on another. In modern debates over GSRM [gender/sexual/romantic minorities] issues, you will hear some people talk about "not letting a minority impose its will on the majority," which sounds right on that one level, and yet wrong on the other. And I wonder if this tension admits of a stable resolution, or whether the balance can only be achieved or maintained by the spontaneous decision to achieve or maintain it. Both levels of freedom find purchase in the original American legendarium: religious minorities escaping clerical oppression alongside political majorities defying unrepresentative government.

But is there any way to *codify* the harmonizing of these interests? You might say that this is what America has done to some extent, down to this very day, but I would ask whether this equilibrium is an illusion of a relatively short history: again, by now, this nation is capable of collapsing so efficiently that I don't know whether we'll see the balance persist (if it even really exists) for much longer.

Without overemphasizing this geographically parochial enigma as such, I will pose my question like so: **is there any reliable non-anarchistic method of reconciling majority rule with minority protections?** What I mean by "non-anarchistic" is "legally mandated," in such a way that psychological mechanisms can be relied on to carry the reconciliation forward, rather than the harmony arising from a constant repetition of the ritual of commitment thereto. I'm not claiming that it is impossible to maintain such a balance, but rather I wonder if it is possible to maintain such a balance in a constitutionalist manner.

And then whether Gödel's loophole has anything to do with this matter, of course.

Comment: This question belongs on a legal or political site.

Comment: *Rolls eyes* If you can't abstract from the example despite all the pointers in the question as to how to do so, and if you can't figure out how to correlate Gödel exegesis with the purpose of this site, that's on you.

Comment: See the post [What was Gödel's Constitutional Problem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242441/what-was-g%c3%b6dels-constitutional-problem)

Comment: @DavidGudeman. It’s on me, too, I guess.

Comment: Here you go: "Is [constitutionalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/constitutionalism/) able to stabilize the twin poles of minority and majority freedom protections?" Certainly this is a question of legal theory, but a lot of people with philosophy BAs go into law in graduate school, and legal theory itself is an object of philosophical reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Karl Schmidt the state of legality is merely a result of temporary power equilibrium (which i understand the "tension" mentioned in your question to be an example of).

It is to say that every single constitution has a loop hole, which is that people at the top of the recourse pyramid can always break the rules by interpreting them in bad faith, and in such a case can be only kept in check by a popular revolt.

For example, in the US(*) people can appeal the decision of any justice court to a higher one, up to the Supreme Court. But no recourse exists against a decision of the Supreme Court. The justices are appointed for life and no other branch of government can contest their decisions.

Now what if the justices were to take liberties with the constitution? Like taking decisions favoring the establishment of a specific religion when the constitution says otherwise? It would be contrary to the constitutional law, but as no recourse can be taken according to the same constitution, if the executive branch is willing to enforce this decision, although it opens the door to tirany it is, for all intent and purpose, legal (and by rebelling against the court they would be acting illegally). The only recourse is disobedience and people marching to the supreme court to remove the justices.

Another example: in France the job of declaring who won the presidential election comes down to the Constitutional Council, based on figures provided by the chief of police (ministre de l'intérieur), who's administration is in charge of centralizing the vote counts. Now, what if the minister provides falsified figures and the Constitutional Council, in on the conspiracy, declares them to be valid? What can the outraged citizens do? No problem! They can adress their claims and evidence... to the Constitutional Council, who can dismiss them as it sees fit. Here again, the council is acting legally although illegitimately, and the only legitimate recourse is an uprising, which is illegal.

Other possibilities are open, like different branches of the government refusing to exert check and balance on each other, etc. No legal system is fool proof, and all rely on the fact that its actors, specifically the key ones acting as a last recourse against overreaching, act in reasonably good faith.

(*) I am not a lawyer, I am not even a us citizen so please correct me if I am wrong on the details. The principle stands, however, that every chain of appeal must have an end and if this end starts acting in bad faith the whole check and balance system is compromised.

Comment: My grounds for accepting this answer are the part that goes, "It is to say that every single constitution has a loop hole," and though there is no "proof" that the example given maps to what Gödel was worried about, it is an option to consider, by me, for the time being.